# How to expend tAssertCatcher to catch more errors than its default in talend?

Tags: stored-procedures, error-handling, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, talend

I have a job which when I run it- I get this:

```
[ERROR] 11:47:54 org.talend.components.snowflake.runtime.SnowflakeRowStandalone- Query execution has 
failed. Please validate your query.
net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: Execution error in store procedure 
SP_GENERAL:
Numeric value '' is not recognized
```

but when I'm trying to catch this error- I cant.
I tried tAssertCatcher, tLogCatcher, tStatCatcher- and nothing has worked.
could anybody help please?

Answer (score 0):

ok, finally I got a solution.
tAssertCatcher does not catch errors from stored procedures, so I created a joblet which contain the tAssertCatcher AND in addition, added in there:

1. input with schema almost identical to tAssertCatcher's schema:
   moment, pid, project, job, language, origin, status, substatus, errorCode, errorMessage.
   now- I connected between the tDBrow component which I want to catch error from this process- with Reject row to the joblet, and pass errorCode and errorMessage- this will be the exception and description.
   in the schema I used tMap to add variables values to almost all the columns:
   pid, status, jobName, projectName and the rest I passed hardcoded.
   finally I got a solution... every time I'll have error in stored procedure- I'll get 2 detailed records: one that I created manually, and the another one is UNEXPECTED-EXCEPTION.

[the additional part in the joblet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnDQm.png)